# Wordpress revolution slider background does not show properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

We have a website : http://kentinflatables.co.uk/

We are using revolution slider on home page. There are 3 slides but only the first one is showing background image and 2 other slides are not.

I'm new here, Please help.
Thank you very much in advance. 
: )

Answer (score 0):

I think you having problem with **background position**. Take a look at this screenshot, you should set it to `center center` to make your background doesn't disappear after the first slide run out. You can also read its [documents](https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/main-background/).

[image]

Comment: Sir, I settings are all okay... do you have some other suggestions...Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Instead of using background, I have added image as a layer. it worked. thank you for the your help